# how to add data to an existing dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dataset and I am adding some values in it by for loop.

```
System.Data.DataSet dsUserResult = new System.Data.DataSet(); 
dsUserResult = new System.Data.DataSet();
for (i= 0; i< 3; i++) {
  dsUserResult = getUserByProgramId(i); //This return some values and store it into the dsUserresult
}
```

Now if the `getUserByProgramId(i) return 4` values when `i=0` , it stores it into dataset, but when it runs again for the second time `(i=1)` , it removes existing dataset value and then add new values, I actually want the new values to be appended with the previous values added in the dataset.

Comment: How many tables and rows in the DataSet object returned from `getUserByProgramId`?

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding some values in the Dataset. You are replacing at each loop the previous values of the *dsUserResult* with a new dataset returned by the call to *getUserByProgramId*. The loop ends and the only dataset present is the last one retrieved from the loop.

A Dataset contains a collection of DataTable. It is in this collection that the value retrieved from the database are stored.

So, I suppose, from the name of the method, that every time you call that method  you retrieve a different set of user stored in the first DataTable of the Dataset returned.

If this is what happens inside the *getUserByProgramId* then you should **Merge** the result of the first loop with the result of the second loop and the third loop. But what you want to merge are the DataTable contained in the DataSet returned.

```
// First dataset used as base...
dsUserResult = getUserByProgramId(0);

// skip the first and get the other two.
for (i=1; i<3; i++) 
{
   // Get another one...
   DataSet ds = getUserByProgramId(i); 

   // Merge the content of the first table currently returned 
   // with the content of the base dataset....
   dsUserResult.Tables[0].Merge(ds.Tables[0]);
}
```

About [DataTable.Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx)
About [Dataset.Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables(v=vs.110).aspx)